# Usage of std::iterator. Converting std::deque<T>::{const_iterator|iterator} to std::iterator<Args...>

Tags: c++, iterator, containers, std

I got interface `IDocument` and `ConcreteDocument` implementing it. I want to allow users to iterate through any concrete document, so Im tried to add `begin()` and `end()` members in interface.

`IDocument`:

```
virtual R begin() const noexept = 0;
```

`R` must be concrete `T` that given by template Interface parameter or method's template parameter (impossible for virtual methods).

What `R` should be?

I tried to use templates for interface, but its a bad idea, bc clients now knows what `ContainerT` `ConcreteDocument` is using.

I tried to use `std::iterator`, but my `ConcreteDocument` e.g. uses `std::deque<T>`, so convertion between `std::iterator` and `std::deque<T>::{const_iterator|iterator}` is undefined

Any ideas?

**Upd:**

**Ok, `std::iterator` is deprecated**

Code example:

```
class IDocument
{
public:
    using Path = StdPath;

    virtual void InsertItem(const ItemT&
        std::optional<size_t> position = std::nullopt)
        = 0;

    virtual size_t GetItemsCount() const = 0;

    virtual const DocumentItem& GetItem(size_t index) const noexcept = 0;

    virtual void DeleteItem(size_t index) = 0;

    virtual const std::string& GetTitle() const = 0;
    virtual void SetTitle(const std::string& title) = 0;

    // `begin()` `end()` methods, but how signature looks like if i don't know what concrete container is used by derived classes?

    virtual ~IDocument() = default;
};

class HTMLDocument : public IDocument
{
public:
    HTMLDocument() = default;

    template <typename StringT = std::string>
    HTMLDocument(StringT&& string)
        : m_title(std::forward<StringT>(string))
        , m_undoManager()
    {
    }


    size_t GetItemsCount() const final;

    const DocumentItem& GetItem(size_t index) const noexcept final;

    void DeleteItem(size_t index) final;

    const std::string& GetTitle() const final;
    void SetTitle(const std::string& title) final;

    void Save(const StdPath& path) const final;

    // here need `begin()` and `end()` methods accessable through IDocument*

private:
    std::string m_title = "Title";
    std::deque<DocumentItem> m_items;

    UndoManager m_undoManager{};
};
```

I need to implement non-member function that outputs Document's content into `std::ostream&`

So, for more handy-usage I want `begin()` and `end()` methods in interface, but I can't figure out whats their signatures are, bc they are based on `ContainerT`

Comment: `std::iterator` is a deprecated class with nothing but a bunch of typedefs in it, you shouldn't need it. What is *"template Interface parameter"*? Can you show more code?

Comment: Here some updates, @HolyBlackCat

Comment: What is the issue with `return m_items.begin()` and `return m_items.end()`?

Comment: @273K, the problem is not that, but that it is unclear what signature the begin() and end() methods should have in the interface, because virtual decltype(auto) begin() will not work

Comment: You seem to have to implement own iterator class supporting required iterator traits.

Comment: Since `IDocument::GetItem` returns a `DocumentItem` (whatever that might be), then I imagine `IDocument::begin()` and `IDocument::end()` should designate a range over a collection of `DocumentItem`. Though I see `ItemT` also make an appearance - what is it and how does it fit into the picture?

Comment: @273K, yeah this will suit up, thanks

Comment: This kind of thing has historically been done in C++ with static, rather than dynamic (virtual) polymorphism: iterators are used as value types, which is problematic with virtual functions. As a result, the entire standard library deals with iterators using lots of template code and, since C++20, concepts.